# Output sound from a laptop's speaker and from an external speaker at the same time

Tags: windows-10, audio, external-display

I have a laptop running Windows 10 and I recently got an extra monitor to use along with it. The thing is, the monitor has built-In speakers and I'm trying to configure my system so that sound would play from both the laptop and the extra monitor at the same time. All I could find on previous threads and other sources online was about how to configure your system to achieve a similar goal with a headset. Tried it, didn't work.

Is there a way to configure my system to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about configuring something like that in system settings, but what comes to my mind is Voicemeeter from vb-audio https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/.

I used it once to stream music from my browser to my microphone, as well as played sound from both my speakers and a bluetooth tower at once (it was horrible due to the latency for bluetooth).

For refence here is the manual: https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf and there are also many tutorials to find on YouTube.

Comment: I downloaded the Voicemeeter app. It technically works, but now if I want to increase/lower the volume, I have to do it manually through the app's control panel, and I couldn't find on the manual how to change this.

Comment: That's what I found: https://voicemeeter.com/volume-control-how-to-change-the-volume-of-your-main-output-without-the-mouse/ . You should be able to assign your normal volume keys.